# how will container start ApplicationContext.xml file

Tags: spring, struts, ioc-container, dao

I already have an application implemented in Struts. I am trying to move it to Spring so I am doing everything step by step. First plan is to implement IOC (DI). now I got my DAOs fixed, i got my applicationContext.xml fixed now when I try to run the application (ofcourse) it does not create beans for me through applicationContext.xml(sometimes known as beans.xml) automatically. In my understanding i need to get my applicationContext.xml initialized before  my service classes call method of my DAOs. what is proper flow of Spring's IOC or how will container start ApplicationContext.xml file.

Comment: what's in the applicationContext.xml? All your bean definitions? Are all of your spring configuration files in the classpath where your web.xml is loading them from?

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the needed tags to the web.xml?

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
  <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
</context-param>

<listener>
 <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Comment: @Aahil Khan: you can click on the checkbox below it to accept the answer.